# Calling a javascript function does not accept a variable parameter

Tags: java, android

The following code is designed within a Fragment to call a javascript file (MyMap) and call a function (updateJSONandMap). The function itself sends a JSON to a server and takes three parameter. It works while the first parameter is hardcoded ("Incident") but will not work when I create a variable.

```
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/MyMap.html");
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    webview.loadUrl("javascript:updateJSONandMap('Incident'," + latitude + "," + longitude + ")");
                }
            });
```

The block of text of the JSON is a string

```
            Event: {
                Action: 'PUT',
                Value: {"S": UserEvent}
            },
```

The obvious create a variable

```
final String incident = "incident2";
```

and then

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:updateJSONandMap(" + incident + "," + latitude + "," + longitude + ")");
```

does not create an error, but does not send the JSON to the server

Comment: obviously incident2 is a variable, 'incident2' is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I think there may be an error in your string, the first `incident` is surrounded by single quotations. Will this string work?

```
"javascript:updateJSONandMap('" + incident + "'," + latitude + "," + longitude + ")";
```

What if you do it this way around?

```
final String incident = "incident2";
String loadUrlParam = `javascript:updateJSONandMap('${incident}', ${latitude}, ${longitude})`;

webview.loadUrl(loadUrlParam);
```

Comment: I just figured this out as I came to type back the answer! Thank you -                             webview.loadUrl("javascript:updateJSONandMap('" + incident + "'," + latitude + "," + longitude + ")");